# How to send message after user's socket disconnect from the server

Tags: node.js, tcp, chat

I'm using net module of node.js to build a chat server based on TCP. I have figured out how to handle the situation where two users both connect to the server. However, for a chat app, even if the user disconnect from the internet, people can still send message to those disconnected users. I just have no idea of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save messages in a database so that when they log in again you can retrieve sent messages and send them all at once.

There is no way to communicate to a user who has logged off.  You just have to queue up the messages and deliver them when they reconnect.

Comment: I thought about this way before but found the implementation overwhelming! But I will try my best to handle the database issues! Thank you very much!